# How to get the first element from an enumset in Java?

Tags: java

I am having problems with this old project that I am working on. Basically, there's this object that stores an enumset to the database and my problem is I need to get the first element of the stored enumset. Now, before you go bash on me saying that sets don't have a particular order and I should use a list, I'd like to inform you that I can't just change the code because I don't know what kind of effect it will have to other parts of the system. @_@
The system is around 3-4 years old and I'm the new guy...so, better make a work around.

For example:

```
Enumset<Protocol> protocolsAvailable;
```

Here is a sample of what it looks like when  protocolAvailable is retrieved from the database:

```
[ALPHA,BETA,EPSILON]
```

I need to get the first element, which is alpha. I can do it several ways, transform it to a list then use get(index), or I can treat it as a string and use .split(",")[0]... eehh... I don't know, it's getting late, and I guess I'm just looking for better ways of doing it. :>

Answer (score 6):

```
protocolsAvailable.iterator().next()
```

is the traditional way to do it.

Comment: aww.. seriously? I've tried it but it doesnt give me alpha, it gives me epsilon instead. :(

Comment: If this is a `java.util.EnumSet`, it'll give you the first one in the order the enums were declared.

Comment: @joannaSmith12 So you want the elements to be reordered alphabetically before selecting the first element?

Comment: ok..wait.. hmm.. nevermind. My dataset was of a different order and when I retrieved it, the order got mixed up.. Whew, it's correct. I need to go to sleep. T_T Will be marking it correct later.